# Client server login

Tags: delphi, authentication, server, client

I have a server available which can be reached via an IP address and port 22. The server can only be accessed via a username and password. If I send the assignment "getinfo" to the server, it will give some text which I need.

I can access this via an SSH client, like KITTY, but how do I do this in Delphi?

I assume that the `TIdTCPClient` component will suffice, but I do not understand how a login can be implemented.

Comment: Indy does not support SSH protocol. You'll need to use components like the one from eldos or other alternatives.

Comment: [Adding support for SSH is on Indy's TODO list](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/18).  In the meantime, you could use 3rd party SSH components, or you can try implementing the [SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/) yourself, sending encoded SSH messages back and forth through `TIdTCPClient` as needed.

Comment: Just like Indy doesn't have RTSP, and many other protocols, implemented in components. You have to implement them yourself.

Comment: I can't find any examples on the internet how to implement this by myself or how to use third pary components. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?